# Why isn't my multiple loops working?

Tags: loop

I would like a multiple look to display `the_content` from the current page, &  from another page. My multiple loo doesn't seem to be working. Can anyone advise, please?

```
while( have_posts() ): the_post();
the_content();
endwhile;

$id=40;
$post = get_post($id);
$title = apply_filters('the_title', $post->post_title);
echo $title;
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content);
echo $content;
endif;
endwhile;
```

Please can someone advise? Thank-you!

Comment: Are you missing some code? I see `endwhile;` twice but `while:` appears only once, and there's no `if:`

Comment: @TomJNowell I seem to have made it work, answer below. Please could I ask you to have a quick look and say if that's how you would do it? I would really appreciate it. Thank-you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This seems to work:**

```
while( have_posts() ): the_post();
    the_content();
endwhile;

$my_query = new WP_Query('page_id=40');
while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
    $do_not_duplicate = $post->ID;?>

        <div class="entry">

            <?php the_content('read more &raquo;'); ?>

        </div>

     <?php
endwhile;
```

Comment: Is this how others would do this? I would really appreciate some tips for improvement. Thank-you all!

Comment: I would indent everything correctly ( your editor should auto-indent for you as you type ), I'd also use the other syntax `while () {}` rather than `while(): while;` as it has wider support in editors and tools ( think brace matching ). I'd also put the call to `the_post` on its own line. I'm not sure why you've got the `$do_not_duplicate` in there. `'pageid=40'` would be better as `array( 'p' => 40 )`

Comment: Also upvoted for answering your own question